# Call a script for another script, but don't exit the parent if the child calls exit

Tags: shell, shell-script, exit

`first.sh`:

```
#! /bin/ksh
echo "prova"
. ./second.sh
echo "ho lanciato il secondo"
. ./third.sh
echo "ho lanciato il terzo"
```

`second.sh`:

```
echo "sono nel secondo script"
dosomething1
exit $?
```

If `second.sh` detects an error and exits with status -9, `first.sh` exits always.
How I can do avoid exiting from the first shell if the child shell exits?

I can't edit `second.sh`.

Comment: Here you are using the `.` command, which sources another file in the current shell. There is no child shell or subshell involved. Did you mean to *execute* `second.sh` and `third.sh` instead of sourcing them?

Comment: yes.. i must write execute instead of . ./ ?  i want ignore "exit $?" inside second.sh.. is possible without edit second.sh?

Answer (score 21):

What you're doing here is including `second.sh` and `third.sh` as sub-scripts running in the same process, which is called “sourcing” in shell programming. `. ./second.sh` is basically equivalent to including the text of `second.sh` at that point. The `exit` command exits the process, it doesn't matter whether you call it in the original script or in a sourced script.

If all you want to do is run the commands in `second.sh` and `third.sh` and they don't need to access or modify variables and functions from the original script, call these scripts as child processes.

```
#! /bin/ksh
echo "prova"
./second.sh
echo "ho lanciato il secondo"
./third.sh
echo "ho lanciato il terzo"
```

If you need the other scripts to access variables and functions from the original script, but not modify them, then call these scripts in subshells. Subshells are separate processes, so `exit` exits only them.

```
#! /bin/ksh
echo "prova"
(. ./second.sh)
echo "ho lanciato il secondo"
(. ./third.sh)
echo "ho lanciato il terzo"
```

If you need to use variables or functions defined in `second.sh` and `third.sh` in the parent script, then you'll need to keep sourcing them.

The `return` builtin exits only the sourced script and not the whole process — that's one of the few differences between including another script with the `.` command and including its text in the parent script. If the sourced scripts only call `exit` at the toplevel, as opposed to inside functions, then you can change `exit` into `return`. You can do that without modifying the script by using an alias.

```
#! /bin/ksh
echo "prova"
alias exit=return
. ./second.sh
echo "ho lanciato il secondo"
. ./third.sh
unalias exit
echo "ho lanciato il terzo"
```

If `exit` is also called inside functions, I don't think there's a non-cumbersome way. A cumbersome way is to set an exit trap and put your code there.

```
#!/bin/ksh
do_first () {
  echo "prova"
  trap "after_second" EXIT
  . ./second.sh
  after_second
}
after_second () {
  echo "ho lanciato il secondo"
  trap "after_third" EXIT
  . ./third.sh
  after_third
}
after_third () {
  trap - EXIT
  echo "ho lanciato il terzo"
}
do_first
```

Comment: It is for this reason that I've stopped using '.' to source files into a script, and try to exclusively use 'source' instead. IMO that should be considered a bash 'best practice', since it makes it much clearer what your code is doing.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of sourcing the second and third shell, just run them as you would any other command. The exit code can be stored and used if you need, like so:

```
#! /bin/ksh
echo "prova"

# execute and capture stdout ... output of second is not seen ...
OUTPUT1=$(./second.sh)

# find out exit status of second.sh
STATUS1=$?

# ... until now
echo $OUTPUT1

# do something based on the result
if [ $STATUS1 -eq 0 ]; then 
  echo "second.sh ran successfully"
else 
  echo "second.sh crapped out"
fi

# and so on...
```

Comment: `STATUS1=$?` will catch result of previously issued echo command, which is independent of result of `./second.sh`.

Comment: @Cromax you're completely right. Answer has been edited.

Comment: Thank you. I used this and adapted it for my menu of menus bash setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way (remove first `.` on calling `second.sh`):

`first.sh`:

```
#! /bin/ksh
echo "prova"
./second.sh
echo "ho lanciato il secondo"
./third.sh
echo "ho lanciato il terzo"
```

`second.sh`:

```
echo "sono nel secondo script"
dosomething1
exit $?
```

This is because `.` is shortcode for `source` which cause the second script to be included as a part of first one.

Answer (score 0):

script1.sh

```
  1 PWD="/scratch/currdir"
  2 echo "Hello from scrpt 1"
  3
  4 sh $PWD/script2.sh # We will exit in script2.sh and see if line 6 gets printed
  5
  6 echo "From script 1: After scrpt2 call"
  7 exit 0
```

script2.sh

```
  1 echo "Hello from script 2"
  2
  3 exit 1
  4 echo "This should not get printed"
```

Output:

```
-bash-4.1$ sh script1.sh
Hello from scrpt 1
Hello from script 2
From script 1: After scrpt2 call
```

(Note: Although we exited script2 (line number 3 with exit 1), but still in script1.sh the line no 6 gets executed post calling script2.sh

Hope this helps.